# Why the while loop is used in this database connection?

Tags: c#

Currectly I am studying and learning and I just wanted to know some logic of this database connection in C#. I wanted to know why the while loop is used I means if I don't use it, will it affect the program or will the program run fine if I take it out. I just wanted to know is it wise to use it or just take it out from the program. Can someone please help me ?? Thank you

```
    private bool filled;
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    private void bnt_displaylog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Elevator_Database.accdb;";
            string dbcommand = "Select * from Log;";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
            OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);

            conn.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! "); 
            **while (filled == false)**
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                filled = true; 
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            string message = "Error in connection to datasource";
            string caption = "Error";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            DialogResult result;
            result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons); 
        }

        database_listbox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
        {
            database_listbox.Items.Add(row["Date"] + "\t\t" + row["Time"] + "\t\t" + row["Action"]); 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Seems it can be easily replaces with `if (!filled) ...` unless there are some other methods accessing `filled` variable.

Comment: do we need loop or if? it seems program is working fine with just having this part  " adapter.Fill(ds);"

Comment: Yes, the `if` is still needed if we want to keep the same behavior it has now. The first time this code is run, `filled` is `false`. But the *next* time the code is run, `filled` will be `true` unless some other code has set it back to `false`. So the code as it is - or changed to an `if` - runs `adapter.Fill(ds);` only on the first click.

Comment: @foxanna unless `Fill` throws an exception and `bnt_displaylog_Click` is called again within dialog on `catch`.

Comment: This method seems to be a button click handler which means it can be executed multiple times. I'd rather perform this check even before opening the connection.

Comment: Thank you it's more clear thaks alot :)

Answer (score 4):

That's just code that was written in a very unclear manner. The `while` loop will never loop at all. The loop body will either be executed once, or not at all, depending on the value of `filled`.

In other words, the code could have been written more clearly as:

```
conn.Open();
if( ! filled )
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    filled = true; 
}
conn.Close();
```

But even then, the code is doing the wrong thing. Think about the case where `filled` is `true`. The code that's actually executed is:

```
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

and what's the point of doing that?

In any case, what the code actually does, either with `while` or `if`, is call `adapter.Fill(ds)` only the first time through. Given that, we should skip setting up the connection entirely when we don't make that call. And let's refactor the code to make it a bit more clear:

```
private bool filled = false;
public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

private void bnt_displaylog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadDisplayLog();

    database_listbox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
    {
        database_listbox.Items.Add(
            row["Date"] + "\t\t" + row["Time"] + "\t\t" + row["Action"]
        ); 
    } 

}

private void loadDisplayLog(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( filled ) return;

    try
    {
        string dbconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Elevator_Database.accdb;";
        string dbcommand = "Select * from Log;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);

        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        filled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        string message = "Error in connection to datasource";
        string caption = "Error";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons); 
    }
}
```

There are still some issues with the exception handling in this code - will the connection be closed if `adapter.Fill(ds);` throws an exception? Oops. But I'll leave the rest as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: This is true even if `adapter.Fill` runs on a different thread. It just would finish executing the loop sooner

Comment: Ah, you're right, of course, since `filled = true;` is the last statement in the loop. Edited to remove the comment about threads, thanks!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET in my opinion the author of such ugly code even did not thought of multi-threading at all. `filled` can be removed.